# how to display htmlspecialchars in PHP

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

How would I make this actually display EXACTLY with PHP?

```
$answer=<script>alert(It converts to HTML.)</script> 
echo "The function is: htmlspecialchars ($answer)."
```

Comment: Is this your exact code?

Comment: I'm trying to show that on the page exactly like that

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$variable = <<<'EOS'
$answer=<script>alert(It converts to HTML.)</script> 
echo "The function is: htmlspecialchars ($answer)."
EOS;
echo htmlspecialchars($variable);
```

This will display the message exactly as you typed it.

Answer (score -1):

`$answer = "<script>alert(It converts to HTML.)</script>"`

`echo "The function is: htmlspecialchars".$answer;`